# Miro for Ubuntu 16 +

Tags: multimedia, video-player, media, miro, audio-player

Is there a way to install Miro for Ubuntu 16?
the latest version is only compatible with ubuntu 15.

I know it has many alternatives but imo, any of them comes close when it comes to GUI. TomaHawk as a nice GUI but it's too big for me.

Comment: It looks like it has been inactive since 2013. I would look for alternatives if I were you.

Comment: Yeah but, I didn't find something really interesting out there.

Comment: Download the [deb files](http://ppa.launchpad.net/pcf/miro-releases/ubuntu/pool/main/m/miro/?C=M;O=D) and try to install it using dpkg (there is a high chance of broken packages ) or gdebi

Comment: @JayakrishnanM I tried that with gdebi but it didn't work. missing dependencies.